# How to find the average of an array of tuples with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
sample_array = [(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)]
```

I need to find the average to output :

```
>> [2,2]
```

I tried the code below

```
np.average(left_lane)
```

but it returns

```
>> 2.0
```

How can I make it so that it returns two values without having to loop?

Comment: [np.average take an axis argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html#numpy.average)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = np.array(sample_array)
np.average(a, axis=0)
```

Or:

```
a.mean(0)
```

Comment: Or... np.apply_along_axis(np.mean, 0, sample_array)

Comment: @ChrisFarr, it's better to use the `axis` parameters of functions than to use `apply_along`.  The latter is just a wrapper around a Python level iteration.